# Rails_admin with has_one issue in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin, has-one, attr-accessible

In rails 5, attr_accessible is removed. So how to use has_one association.
Like I have:

```
class Setter
  include Mongoid::Document

  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created::Short

  has_one :user
end
```

and

```
class user
  include Mongoid::Document

  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created::Short

  belongs_to :setter
end
```

Right now I am getting no dropdown box for user field in new setter in rails_admin form.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to set `attr_accessible` in the model anymore.

Rather use [strong params](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

Comment: still getting the same error as in the image. The user field have not input or dropdown menu.

Comment: I added the following:

def user_id
    self.user.try :id
  end

  def user_id=(id)
    self.user = User.find_by_id(id)
  end

Comment: And the problem was solved. The bug was the specification of setter and getter id.